# Add items dynamically to List<Integer> and convert to Integer[] Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, integer

I have 2 arrays of strings

```
  String[] s = {"Light", "Sun", "Sun", "Water"};
  String[] ss = {"on", "off", "on", "off"};
```

which I want to convert to an array of integers to assign pictures from my resource later.
Therefor the strings gets checked by switch statement to assign a specific  integer value:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
  {
  switch (components[i]) {

            case "Light":
                  if (ss[i]=="on")
                    I.add(1);
                  else
                    I.add(2);
            case "Sun":
                  if (ss[i]=="on")
                    I.add(3);
                  else
                    I.add(4);
            case "Water":
                  if (ss[i]=="on")
                    I.add(5);
                  else
                    I.add(6);
            case "Gravel":
                  if (ss[i]=="on")
                    I.add(7);
                  else
                    I.add(8);
            }
         }
  }
```

Because i cannot add values dynamically to an array, i decided to create an List of Integers first, and convert it to an integer array later:

```
  List<Integer> I = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  [...]
  Integer[] arr = I.toArray(new Integer[I.size()]);
```

But Instead of my expected result:

```
{"1", "4", "3", "6"}
```

i will get always an sequence of numbers as result:

```
{"1", "2", "3", "4"}
```

It seems like I'm doing something wrong with the converting?

Here the complete code:

```
  public static Integer[] toImg(String[] s, String[] ss) {

        List<Integer> I = new ArrayList<Integer>();

           for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
  {
  switch (components[i]) {

            case "Light":
                  if (ss[i]=="on")
                    I.add(1);
                  else
                    I.add(2);
            case "Sun":
                  if (ss[i]=="on")
                    I.add(3);
                  else
                    I.add(4);
            case "Water":
                  if (ss[i]=="on")
                    I.add(5);
                  else
                    I.add(6);
            case "Gravel":
                  if (ss[i]=="on")
                    I.add(7);
                  else
                    I.add(8);
            }
         }

        Integer[] arr = I.toArray(new Integer[I.size()]);
        return arr;
  }
```

Comment: Switch statements need breaks after each case otherwise they will trigger the rest of the cases. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Thank you user3837868, I was missing the breaks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first and foremost problem with your code is that you are looking over the components array and there is no such field defined in your method but instead according to your problem statement it should be

```
switch (s[i])
```

And then there is also problem with your switch statement as they end without the break statement making them run for all cases whether or not it is the case.
You can better understand by my implementation of your code which looks like

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Test
{
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{

   List<Integer> I = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String[] s = {"Light", "Sun", "Sun", "Water"}; 
    String[] ss = {"on", "off", "on", "off"};
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) { 
        switch (s[i]) { 
            case "Light": 
            if (ss[i]=="on") 
            I.add(1); 
            else 
            I.add(2); 
            case "Sun": 
            if (ss[i]=="on") 
            I.add(3); 
            else 
            I.add(4); 
            case "Water": 
            if (ss[i]=="on") 
            I.add(5); 
            else 
            I.add(6); 
            case "Gravel": 
            if (ss[i]=="on") 
            I.add(7); 
            else 
            I.add(8); 
            } 
            System.out.println(I+" at i="+i);
        } 
    Integer[] arr = I.toArray(new Integer[I.size()]);
    System.out.println(I);
}
}
```

So here is the code you have written and when I run it I get the output

```
[1, 3, 5, 7] at i=0
[1, 3, 5, 7, 4, 6, 8] at i=1
[1, 3, 5, 7, 4, 6, 8, 3, 5, 7] at i=2
[1, 3, 5, 7, 4, 6, 8, 3, 5, 7, 6, 8] at i=3
[1, 3, 5, 7, 4, 6, 8, 3, 5, 7, 6, 8]
```

So you can see that always all case are run and based on the value of ss[] the output arrives.
So you can correct the code as

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Test
{
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{

   List<Integer> I = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String[] s = {"Light", "Sun", "Sun", "Water"}; 
    String[] ss = {"on", "off", "on", "off"};
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) { 
        switch (s[i]) { 
            case "Light": 
            if (ss[i]=="on") 
            I.add(1); 
            else 
            I.add(2);
            break;
            case "Sun": 
            if (ss[i]=="on") 
            I.add(3); 
            else 
            I.add(4);
            break; 
            case "Water": 
            if (ss[i]=="on") 
            I.add(5); 
            else 
            I.add(6);
            break;
            case "Gravel": 
            if (ss[i]=="on") 
            I.add(7); 
            else 
            I.add(8); 
            break;
            } 
            System.out.println(I+" at i="+i);
        } 
    Integer[] arr = I.toArray(new Integer[I.size()]);
    System.out.println(I);
}
}
```

And the output would be

```
[1] at i=0
[1, 4] at i=1
[1, 4, 3] at i=2
[1, 4, 3, 6] at i=3
[1, 4, 3, 6]
```

Which is the required answer.
Hope I have made myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

what is components array in your code?? if you really need to return an array, you are better going to use `for` loop to add elements from collection - it will look more transparent. Don't forget that strings in `switch` statement cannot be null.
In conclusion you can use `IntStream` to move elements, if you want to